# Recyclerview opens different Activities with OnClick

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

This is the first time that I work with a RecyclerView, I can display a `Toast` for each item but I can't seem to get the `getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()` in my `onBindViewHolder`to get the position of my items so that I can make a switch to open a different Activity for each of them.

MyMovieAdapter.java

```
public class MyMovieAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyMovieAdapter.ViewHolder> {

MyMovieData[] myMovieData;
Context context;

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final MyMovieData myMovieDataList = myMovieData[position];
    holder.textViewName.setText(myMovieDataList.getMovieName());
    holder.textViewDate.setText(myMovieDataList.getMovieDate());
    holder.movieImage.setImageResource(myMovieDataList.getMovieImage());

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, myMovieDataList.getMovieName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(TAG, "position = " + holder.getAbsoluteAdapterPosition());

            final Intent intent;
            switch (getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()){
                case 0:
                    intent =  new Intent(context, Activity1.class);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    intent =  new Intent(context, Activity2.class);
                    break;

                default:
                    intent =  new Intent(context, Activity3.class);
                    break;
            }
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

I tried putting the OnClick in the MainActivity like that :

```
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
    Context context=view.getContext();
    Intent intent= new Intent();
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            intent =  new Intent(context, Activity1.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work either. Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Answer: I forgot to put `holder.` before my `getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()`.

Comment: You wrote `getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()` instead of `holder.getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()` in your switch in MyMovieAdapter.java. Maybe that's the issue.

Comment: @JanRozenbajgier Exactly that! It was so simple I can't believe I missed it, thank you!